# Disable powersaving features on a usb3 drive in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, external-hard-drive, powersave

A friend lent me a 4TB external usb3 hdd to copy some files to it. However the drive switches to powersaving mode despite file transfers being active every few 100 GB which will corrupt any transfers in flight and makes it annoying to copy everything to it (I'm not about to sit next to my computer for hours, copy a 200 GB, unmount the drive, mount it back again, copy 200 GB more and so on).

Obviously smartctl/hdparm don't work since usb3 doesn't pass on commands sent using them.

So how to disable this 'feature' so I can just set it to copy 4TB and leave it alone until it's done? It's not my usb3 controller since other large external drives don't enter power saving mode during active use. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have no explanation as to why the device is suspended when in use.

To disable auto-suspend on the device, try this command as root:

```
echo "on" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/your-USB-device/power/level
```

Comment: It could be a faulty LPM -link power management, flaky in U1 and U2 states (not U3/suspend). Is there a similar way to disable LPM?